# Wordpress Multisite смена подкаталогов

Tags: wordpress

На сайте уже реализован мультисайтинг на подкаталогах:

site.com - на рус

site.com/en - на англ

Как теперь сделать, чтобы site.com/en открывался под основным доменом, а основной под site.com/ru ?

**Надо:**

site.com         --> site.com/ru

site.com/en   --> site.com

Answer (score 1):

> Как теперь сделать, чтобы site.com/en открывался под основным доменом, а основной под site.com/ru ?

Если это действительно  [мультисайт](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8), то только перемещением контента в соответствующие сайты (и перенастройками при необходимости).

*А вообще для мультязычности нужен не мультисайт, а плагины мультиязычности.*